# Semi-axes of ellipsoid

Tags: calculus, geometry

Suppose that we have the ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{\left( \frac{\sqrt{c}}{2}\right)^2}+\frac{y^2}{(\sqrt{c})^2}+\frac{z^2}{\left( \frac{\sqrt{c}}{3} \right)^2}=1$.

Then the semi-axes are these ones: $\frac{\sqrt{c}}{2}, \sqrt{c}, \frac{\sqrt{c}}{3}$.

What do the semi-axes represent? What information  do we get from them?

Also why is the set $\{ (x,y,z,t) | t=4x^2+y^2, z=0\}$ a paraboloid of revolution?

Comment: $ y^2+z^2= 4 f \cdot ( x-t)\, ; ( x=>t) $represents a paraboloid of revolution, $f$ being its focal length.

Answer (score 1):

They represent half maximum dimensions ( like diameter) separately in *three* dimensions. For a sphere *three of them are same*, for a surface of revolution *two* axes are same.

[ELLIPSOID](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ellipsoid&biw=1074&bih=478&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwidg_Xph8bLAhUKno4KHVIqDLkQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=hbt2k_DQUdxTJM%3A)

Please note coefficients of x,y,z are of different degree in ellipsoid and paraboloid:

$$ y^2+z^2= 4 f \cdot ( x-t)\, for\, x > t  ; $$

represents a paraboloid having all intersections with same constant focal length $f$

Comment: Suppose that we have the ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$. The semi-axes are the vectors of the origin to the intersection points of the axes and the ellipsoid, and these semi-axes have length $a$, $b$ and $c$. 
Or not?

Comment: The semi axes lengths are scalars, locally maximum or minimum length. Not only these radial rays at ends of axes $a,b,c$ but also each and every point on the ellipsoid can be considered a radial vector.